# How can I make an array with all columns as wide as the widest one?

Tags: support, mathjax, formatting

For example, let's say I wanted to make this diagram of a board in the game 2048:

$$
\begin{array}{|r|r|}
\hline
1024 & \color{white}{0}512 & \color{white}{00}16 & \color{white}{000}2 \\
\hline
2 & 2 & 4 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\\
\text{(etc.)}
$$

Here's the source for the first row:

```
1024 & \color{white}{0}512 & \color{white}{00}16 & \color{white}{000}2 \\
```

As you can see, it's very hacky, and coloring the zeroes white isn't the best solution since it won't work on sites with different backgrounds. (It's also extremely limited, and only works for purely numbers in the cells.)

Is there any way I could make these columns the same width, without having to add ugly invisible zeroes?

Comment: You can use `\phantom` to make white space of a particular width, but it's not much less hacky than what you've done already.

Comment: `\phantom{whatever}` is a better hack than `\color{white}{whatever}`. Imagine you highlight the text.

Comment: I know TeX lets you specify a template for each column; if that is supported here you could use `\hphantom{0000}` as the template. But I don't know if it is supported here.

Comment: Interesting question. This is [hard in TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46797/make-each-column-of-a-table-have-same-width) but [trivial in MathML](http://cdpn.io/xFfaA) -- `<mtable>` comes with an `equalcolumns` attribute. You could file a feature request at [MathJax's github tracker](https://github.com/mathjax/mathjax/issues); not sure how we'd integrate it but it seems an interesting question.